# NSDate object not showing exact date

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am facing a strange problem with a `NSDate` object, I want to fetch records from Core Data that lies between two dates. It seems okay when the dates are different but when I am trying to fetch from same dates it gives me nothing. I tried to set the hours for both dates with the above code:

```
// This is for starting date
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

NSDateComponents *dateComps = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:date1];

[dateComps setHour:00];
[dateComps setMinute:00];
[dateComps setSecond:00];
NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"];
NSString *fdate=[formatter stringFromDate:itemDate];
```

here, `fdate` gives me the date in form of string as I wants (`2012-12-11 12:00 AM`). but when I try to convert it to `NSDate` with the above code;

```
NSDate *dt=[formatter dateFromString:fdate];
```

it just completely destroys my efforts with the above output (`2012-12-10 18:30:00 +0000`). Please suggest what I have to do to stop this.

Comment: this question has been answered here like a thousand times. Please use the search.

Comment: This is converted to GMT, and I would like to suggest always use locale, to make this machine and timezone enabled.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Please provide me some code for that if you have.

Comment: NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"EN"]];
NSDate *myDate=[dateFormatter dateFromString:@"Fri, 07 Dec 2012 08:40:33 +0100"];
NSLog(@"--> %@",myDate);


NSString *rechange=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:myDate];

NSLog(@"==> %@",rechange);

Comment: @AnoopVaidya still same results.

Comment: That is what I said... you will always get in GMT...and never try to change. Because it is localized to your system preferences... and one line added as serLocale: is must to have. and timzone +0530 or +0100 makes sense to everyone. so dont panic :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSDate date method returns wrong result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454387/nsdate-date-method-returns-wrong-result)