# Get date from UTC string

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Here I'm getting a date in string format when I try to convert that string into a date it's getting null. How to get date from below function directly.

```
-(NSString *)getLocalDateTimeFromUTC:(NSString *)strDate
    {
    // create dateFormatter with UTC time format
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZ"]; //@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZ"
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strDate]; // create date from string

    // change to a readable time format and change to local time zone
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
    NSString *timestamp = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSDate *date2 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:timestamp];
    NSLog(@"%@", date2); //Mon Dec  2 00:00:00 2019. wrong formate
    return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
}
```

Comment: I'm getting date string (03-12-2019)

Comment: I want this in NSDate not in string

Comment: Can you please correct it

Comment: Once again I'm trying to convert it like this 'NSString *timestamp = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSDate *date2 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:timestamp]; 
    NSLog(@"%@", date2);'   But getting wrong date.  (Tue Dec  3 00:00:00 2019)

Comment: whats your input string

Comment: My input string is "2019-12-03T06:29:32.445Z"

Comment: I'm expecting (03-12-2019) in NSDate not NSString. For compare two dates

Comment: @iOS - [NSDate date method returns wrong result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454387/nsdate-date-method-returns-wrong-result)

Comment: your code is fine and correct, what the concept you are trying now.

Comment: @ Anbu.Karthik, i'm sending "2019-12-03T06:29:32.445Z" this formate in string. Finally, i want "03-12-2019" formate in NSDate

Comment: @iOS - nsdate does not return correct date always.

Comment: @ Anbu.Karthik, can you please correct it

Comment: @iOS - please check the above link

Comment: @ Anbu.Karthik it's not working...

Answer (score 0):

The conversion back to date is irrelevant. Remove the lines.

And set the locale always to a fixed value (en_US_POSIX)

```
-(NSString *)getLocalDateTimeFromUTC:(NSString *)strDate
    {
    // create dateFormatter with UTC time format
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"; //@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZ"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strDate]; // create date from string

    // change to a readable time format and change to local time zone
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd-MM-yyyy";
    dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    NSString *timestamp = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"%@", timestamp); 
    return timestamp;
}
```