# Getting next date when trying to convert NSDate to String

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have this date in actuall

```
2016-09-03 19:00:00 +0000
```

Now I am trying to convert it to String using a specific format like below

[image]

But what I am getting in return is not as desired. the formatter is adding on day to the given date  like below

[image]

Is this standard behaviour ?

Comment: timeZone is important when your are converting date , pls set time zone and check again

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229024/nsdate-format-outputting-wrong-date

Comment: no need to deal with timeZone, when using NSDateFormatter local timezone it is used by default

Comment: don't post screen shots

Comment: @LeoDabus will keep that in mind next time thanks :-)

Comment: @UmairAfzal Also your code it is incomplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not standard behaviour. This happen because of the time zone difference. Set time zone proper

Set the timezone.

```
formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation: @"GMT"];
```

Answer (score 1):

When you hover over the date, you can see that it is showing UTC, whereas the formatter is automatically converting this to a local date. If your timezone is 5 hours ahead of UTC, then it will be the next day locally from that time.